# Special values don't work as keys in unordered_map

Tags: c++, r, boost, rcpp

For special values like `NA` or `NaN`, `boost::unordered_map` creates a new key each time I use `insert`.

```
// [[Rcpp::depends(BH)]]
#include <boost/unordered_map.hpp>
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
void test_unordered_map(NumericVector vec) {

  boost::unordered_map<double, int> mymap;
  int n = vec.size();
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    mymap.insert(std::make_pair(vec[i], i));
  }

  boost::unordered_map<double, int>::iterator it = mymap.begin(), end = mymap.end();
  while (it != end) {
    Rcout << it->first << "\t";
    it++;
  }
  Rcout << std::endl;
}

/*** R
x <- c(sample(10, 100, TRUE), rep(NA, 5), NaN) + 0
test_unordered_map(x)
*/
```

Result:

```
> x <- c(sample(10, 100, TRUE), rep(NA, 5), NaN)

> test_unordered_map(x)
nan nan nan nan nan nan 4   10  9   5   7   6   2   3   1   8
```

How do I create only one key for `NA` and one for `NaN`?

Comment: You'll have to give it some other value but how I'm not sure.  [this is the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10034149/why-is-nan-not-equal-to-nan)

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1565164/what-is-the-rationale-for-all-comparisons-returning-false-for-ieee754-nan-values) for some insight...

Comment: `NaN` is not equal to itself in c++. Since keys match when they compare equal, you can never match a key whose value is `NaN`.

Comment: It is not a good idea to use double as key of map anyway besides this problem

Comment: I find the concept of using a `double` as a key a bit strange. Not just because it breaks down for `NaN` values, but also because it may behave unexpectedly if you need to calculate a key, due to floating point rounding error.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Using double as key ain't that bad in regular map. But true, in hash map comparing for equality is quite used and double is not the best for this one.

Comment: Florian you are mixing _R extensions_ with standard IEEE behaviour.  R has NaN, NA and NULL, C++ only has NaN.  I think this is a thinko on your part.  You need to map these differently.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[bartop's idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51986233/8416610) of using a custom comperator is good, although the particular form did not work for me. So I used [Boost's documentation](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/doc/html/unordered/hash_equality.html) as starting point. Combined with suitable [functions from R](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/780021752eb83a71e2198019acf069ba8741103b/src/main/arithmetic.c#L122-L139) I get:

```
// [[Rcpp::depends(BH)]]
#include <boost/unordered_map.hpp>
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

struct R_equal_to : std::binary_function<double, double, bool> {
  bool operator()(double x, double y) const {
    return (R_IsNA(x) && R_IsNA(y)) ||
      (R_IsNaN(x) && R_IsNaN(y)) ||
      (x == y);
  }
};

// [[Rcpp::export]]
void test_unordered_map(NumericVector vec) {

  boost::unordered_map<double, int, boost::hash<double>, R_equal_to> mymap;  
  int n = vec.size();
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    mymap.insert(std::make_pair(vec[i], i));
  }

  boost::unordered_map<double, int>::iterator it = mymap.begin(), end = mymap.end();
  while (it != end) {
    Rcout << it->first << "\t";
    it++;
  }
  Rcout << std::endl;
}

/*** R
x <- c(sample(10, 100, TRUE), rep(NA, 5), NaN) + 0
test_unordered_map(x)
*/
```

Result:

```
> x <- c(sample(10, 100, TRUE), rep(NA, 5), NaN) + 0

> test_unordered_map(x)
7   2   nan nan 4   6   9   5   10  8   1   3
```

As desired, `NA` and `NaN` are inserted only once. However, one cannot differentiate between them in this output, since R's `NA` is just a [special form of an IEEE NaN](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51686558/8416610).

Answer (score 5):

According to the IEEE standard, NaN values compared with `==` to anything yeilds always false. So, You just cannot do it this way. You can provide Your own comparator for `unordered_map` using this [`std::isnan`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/isnan) function.

```
auto comparator = [](auto val1, auto val2) {
    return std::isnan(val1) && std::isnan(val2) || val1 == val2;
}
boost::unordered_map<double, int, boost::hash<double>, decltype(comparator)> mymap(comparator);
```

Comment: I would like to differentiate `NA` from `NaN`.

Comment: @F.Privé Afaik there is no such value as NA in c++

Comment: From the C API of R, you have `NA_REAL` and `R_NaN`. You can test specificly for `NA` with `R_IsNA()`.

Comment: @F.Privé Maybe You should use R api types then, not just plain `double`